# PyQT remove border and change button color when pressed

Tags: pyqt

I'm using PyQT and I have a button that I want to remove the border of, and then when it is clicked I also want it to change color.

I remove the border using:

```
self.ui.button_name.setStyleSheet("border: 0px;")
```

I change the color using:

```
self.ui.button_name.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:pressed {background-color: #BDBCBD};")
```

Each of these separately does what I want it to do, but when used together the border stays. I have done each as separate commands, as shown above, as well as in one command like below

```
self.ui.button_name.setStyleSheet("border: 0px; QPushButton:pressed {background-color: #BDBCBD};")
```

And still, there is a border around the button. If I include the border command within the :pressed operation, then when the button is pressed the border gets removed, but that is not the desired outcome.

Comment: You cannot set generic properties along with selector types. Change to `QPushButton { border: none; } QPushButton:pressed {background-color: #BDBCBD; }`. Also don't use the semicolon after the end of a selector bracket. Do some research on basic CSS syntax and read the official [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html).